# My get avatar command is no longer working after I imported discord_components, why?

Tags: python, discord.py

this is my code

```
@client.command(pass_context=True,name='avatar')
async def av(ctx, *, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.send(user.avatar_url)
```

So it all went good but after I imported discord_components to my code, it's no longer working how do I fix this?

Comment: this works perfectly fine at list for me

Comment: ill ask some stupid Q beacuse those are the only things I can think of that could do it did you call it with the correct prefix? is your bot online before you do the command? did you call avatar? did you put the correct token?

Comment: every question of yours is a yes i did everything correctly

Comment: try to maybe have at the creation of the client also `intents = discord.Intents.all()`

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Comment: please read [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)

Comment: i already did every steps since last month and it still is not working

Comment: the real thing is if you have in the discord developer site the settings that they want enbaled

Comment: yes that's what i meant i already enabled everything that is supposed to in order to make a bot

Answer (score -1):

#### discord.Member works properly

```py
@client.command(name="avatar")
async def av(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    await ctx.send(f"{member.avatar_url}")
```

Comment: "It's discord.Member" -- *why?* `discord.User` also has the `avatar_url` attribute... I don't see how is this supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: Try it out and let me know if *it doesn't solve the problem*